# Namespacing Hierarchy, Minify and Cross-Browser Compatibility

Tags: javascript, compression, minify

I've been using the following model for Namespacing my newest Scripts. So far, it has some distinct advantages that, while I'm sure could be replicated in other ways, really help to in my coding process. Unfortunately, I've come across a significant disadvantage... When using some JS compression utilities, they mangle the code badly enough that I must avoid many advantageous options. ***Luckily, the code I save with this model helps mitigate the "damages".***

I'm still curious to know if there is a more viable solution as the min.js only fail consistently in Chrome/IE. I know the below is a little too abstract for some. Are there any experts that might point me in the right direction. I've used YUI, Packer and JSMin. JSMin works reliably, but is not nearly as efficient...

```
/* Global Namspace */
(function (T) {"use strict";
    /* Top.Sub1 */
    (function(S1) {


        // ... Some methods (public/private)


        /* Top.Sub1.Mini */
        (function(M) {

            // ... Some methods (public/private)

        }(S1.Mini = S1.Mini || function(o){}));
    }
    (T.Sub1 = T.Sub1 || function(o){}));

    /* Top.Sub2 */
    (function(S2) { 

        // ... Some methods (public/private)

        /* Top.Sub2.Mini1 */
        (function(M1) {

            // ... Some methods (public/private)

        }(S2.Mini1 = S2.Mini1 || function(o) {}));

        /* Top.Sub2.Mini2 */
        (function(M2) {

            // ... Some methods (public/private)

        }(S2.Mini2 = S2.Mini2 || function(o) {}));
    } (T.Sub2 = T.Sub2 || function(o) {}));

} (window.Namespace = window.Namespace || function(o){}));
```

**UPDATE:** The most common error I am faced with is "unexpected token" of various sorts.. sometimes a ')' and sometimes a '}'. Every once in a while, it is a '('. I haven't yet addressed gzip as I want this out of the way.

**UPDATE 2:** Have checked/removed ns with a Tidied-jsHint passing file and still does not minify correctly. It definitely has to do with this model... Does anyone have a clear answer as to why? If not, further recommendations are welcome. *P.S. the Github has been updated with Tidied-jsHint passing code.*

Comment: Why do use function object `function(o){}` instead of just plain object like `{}`? Are you using it as a constructor later?

Comment: In the working code it is a constructor, yes. This alleviates the need to have an independent init method. Ultimately, it allows a NS, NS() or new NS(). I'm not yet ready to use Object.create()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing nearly every option on every minifier I could get my hands on, the code minifies quite fine. (With and without the tidy, etc...) The issue comes when any of the minifiers try to replace or obfuscate symbols. In particular, it does not handle this for loop well:

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) { 
    _.points[i] = new S.Point(_, pts[i]);
}
```

Removal of the loop allows for the optimization to occur correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say read this article about what needs to be done and what needs to be avoided for good minification – http://alistapart.com/article/javascript-minification-part-II

And then choose a proper modules framework like [AMD](http://addyosmani.com/writing-modular-js/) or [commonjs](http://dailyjs.com/2010/10/18/modules/).

**UPD**. My main advice will be to use a linter on your code like http://jshint.com and adhere to a coding style like http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml It mostly comes with explanations of why something will break in certain sitautions. It's also going to make your code more approachable for open source contributors.

Comment: While it is not stated, I am using some frameworks. The issue is not the lack of framework `(as many frameworks use the (f(a){}(a = win.a || {}));` syntax. I'll certainly read the article though. It is especially important to realize the CODE works well across all browsers... it is the minify that does not.

Comment: This article does not address my question. It simply refers to good coding practice (which any long-term OO programmer like myself would already have). The issue here is not code practice, but the inability to minify 100% compatible (AFAIK) code given specific constraints.

Comment: Can you show an example of particular code that breaks after minificataion? My point about modules is that you'd win quite a lot compared to these closures approach by separating your logic into separate files and managing dependencies explicitly through the use of `require` statements.

Comment: This is a plugin I am developing for the jQuery framework, which recommends using a IIFE-closure for namespacing. Due to the complexity of the Plugin, these IIFEs significantly simplify the code. In order to maintain independence from jQuery, I manage multiple namespaces. The code is at https://github.com/FuzzicalLogic/Juice ... working examples at http://fuzzicallogic.github.com/Juice/

Comment: Are you using a linter with your code? Something like jshint.com? After minifaction is ran, things like omitting semicolon in a certain place may break things for you, I tried to run your code through linter but there are way too many errors – there are many line breaks in places they shouldn't be, I'd say try to format your code according to something like http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml It mostly comes with explanations of why something will break in certain sitautions. It's also going to make your code more approachable for open source contributors.

Comment: Before I minify, I use tidy to fix line-breakage. Nearly all of those errors go away. And yes, I use jsLint. I'm not sure of the advantages of jsHint over jsLint are.

Comment: Well I see loads of Lint errors on your code even after I try to beautify it. Not sure what else I could recommend.

Comment: I think you're getting side tracked. jsLint is a code quality tool for making sure that your code works consistently. I have verified that it does work consistently. The articles you have provided are not any help. I've now cleaned/fixed my code (even though I've been working on it today) and minify is still not working.

Comment: I was trying to politely note that your code is very hard to read so even looking for what's wrong with code itself is hard. I'm 99% it has to do with variable `ns` and the way its used. The code is complex for no obvious reason.

Comment: Rather than criticize the *in development* code, you might try sticking to the issue at hand. The issue at hand is that it minifies using other models, but the other models are not as versatile. This model is more versatile, more compact, and allows for more independence, but does not minify. I'm searching for an answer as to why this model works consistently, but doesn't minify. *As a note:* I'm aware my code is hard to read for others. It stays that way until its ready to be useful to others, period. I will explore 'ns' as the culprit.